# Jira and Salesforce integration: example code - how to implement REST API to create your own connector?

Tags: integration

There have already been a few questions posted asking 'how to integrate Jira and Salesforce'. The general consensus is that a paid for connector is the best route to go. The main providers are Service Rocket (looks like the best, so far), zAgile, go2group and Timeline.

However, for those who don't want to go down the route of leveraging a paid for connector and would like to create their own, there is practically no example code showing how this can be achieved.

It seems like it should be possible and the last response posted May 13 2015 [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008s12IAA)  gives a high level overview on one possible solution, however there isn't any sample code.

Can anyone provide some sample code (or even pseudo code) on how to integrate Jira and Salesforce using the REST API? Or, would anyone not recommend to go down that route anyway (some of the app reviews for the aforementioned apps hint that, in their experience, the paid for connectors are the best way to integrate the two platforms).

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Some apex code to connect to the [Jira API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis)? What have you tried so far? Where about's are you stuck on it?

Comment: Really going to depend on what you are actually trying to do here. One way? Two way? The connectors are good because most work two way, where a purely Salesforce solution would only be one way from SF to Jira.